# Flutter App- App rejected on 4.2 Design: Minimum Functionality

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I finished developing my app and uploaded it to Google Play, but I encountered an issue when attempting to publish it on the App Store. Apple displayed a message to me.

[image]

My app includes a list of coupons, the ability to add coupons to favorites, a search function for coupons, categorized options, push notifications, and a login/sign up feature through Firebase.
my app have same things like this [app](https://apps.apple.com/ae/app/coupon-rush-%D9%83%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%B1%D8%B4-%D9%84%D9%84%D9%83%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AA/id1484306513) except shop trends section.

I provided a detailed description and included a screenshot, but my submission was rejected for the third time.

Comment: Questions regarding App Store review are off topic,  but you should consider Apple's advice - how does your app deliver an experience that couldn't be delivered by a web site?